# htaccessでwww付きにリダイレクトする前に「安全ではない接続」と表示される

Tags: apache, ssl, .htaccess, https, amazon-elb

ELB-EC2-apache
でサーバーを構築しております。
証明書はwww付きのモノですので、
https://example.com と接続すると「安全ではない接続」と表示されるので、

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

のように設定しているのですが、
https://example.com にアクセスすると
「安全ではない接続」と表示され、許可してアクセスした後にwww付きにリダイレクトされます。

ネットで沢山情報ありますので、いろいろ試しましたが「安全ではない接続」と表示されます。
このパターンですと、どのようにwww付きにリダイレクトさせれば良いのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

サーバーの設定に関係なく、ユーザーが https://example.com にアクセスした時点で https://example.com の正しい証明書が存在しないようなので、ユーザーから見ればそれは「安全ではない接続」になります。

SNI などを使い証明書が example.com に対して有効である状態にしない限り、安全にリダイレクトさせることは SSL の仕組み上できません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ELBではSNIが使用できないようです( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html )が、SANで解決できるようですので、そちらで対応したいと思います。

Comment: FYI:  ''SNI'' と ''SAN''の違いについて   https://www.marineroad.com/staff-blog/10307.html